# async operator on undefined observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs6

I have a component which shows information only if the `observable` has data. but when I try to use `async` operator on the `observable` I **don't see** any value. I am confused with the way how **async pipe** works I think it takes some **time to initialize the observable** in that case `async pipe` will not do anything on undefined observable and that's why the component is not showing.

```ts
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="todo$ | async as todo">
      <div {{todo.name}} </div>
    </div>   
  `
})
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  todo$: Observable<Todo>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todo$ = this.store
      .pipe(select(selectTodos));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }
}
```

I know that `async` pipe will handle `Observable` but what if Observable is still **undefined** will async pipe handle that scenario too. if so is there any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong please note that I have subscribed and check if observable has data.

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in your store ? Have you check with Redux DevTools ?

And you `todos$` in your html. It is not defined in you component. BUT `todo$` yes

Comment: Are you using NgRx or NGXS as state manager?

Comment: @wandrille sorry i edited the question. That was not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async pipe also works with multiple, delayed and initially undefined observables. I made a stackblitz for you to see:

[multiple-observable-assigns](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-observable-assigns)

It seems like you never get any data out of your `select(selectTodos)`

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```html
<ul *ngIf="(todos$ | async).length">
  <li *ngFor="let todo of todos$ | async">{{todo.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

First you have to using *ngIf then you need to use for loop to print it

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of code issues. @Wandrille mentioned the first one -- you're referencing `todos` instead of `todo` in your template. In addition, you don't have a closing angle bracket for the opening `<div>` tag for the `{{todo.name}}` text. I would expect either of these issues to lead to a compilation error, though. Is your code exactly as listed?

Another likely issue would be that you're attempting to get the `name` element out of an array (i.e., perhaps `todos$` should be of type `Observable<Todo[]>`). In this case, you will need to adjust your type declarations (and the `selectTodos` selector if applicable) and then iterate appropriately:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="todos$ | async as todos">
      <div *ngFor="let todo of todos">
        {{todo.name}}
      </div>
    </div>   
  `
})
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  todos$: Observable<Todo[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todos$ = this.store
      .pipe(select(selectTodos));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }
}
```